# Find $\tan \left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)$, given $\sin (\theta) = \frac 35$, with $90^\circ < \theta < 180^\circ$

Tags: trigonometry

Find tan theta/2, given sin theta = 3/5, with 90^∘ < theta < 180^∘.
I don't know how to solve it! Help? do I use the tangent half-identity formula?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please give some context (by adding to your question text), in particular, tell us what you've tried so far, including anything you had difficulty with. Also, letting us know where this problem comes from would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Use the formula $\sin\theta=\frac{2t}{1+t^2}$ where $t=\tan(\theta/2)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that$$\tan\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)=\frac{\sin\theta}{1+\cos\theta}$$

$$90^{\circ}<\theta<180^{\circ}\implies\theta\in\text{Quadrant}\space II$$

If we know that $\sin\theta=\frac{3}{5}$ in Quadrant $II$, then drawing the appropriate triangle in Quadrant $II$ will show that $$\cos\theta=-\frac{4}{5}$$

It helps to notice that this is a $3-4-5$ triangle. Now that we know $\sin\theta$ and $\cos\theta$ as required by the original identity for $\tan\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)$, we can plug those values into the identity.